# Abelian category which is nice and its dual is also

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

Is there a nontrivial abelian category $C$ such that both $C$ and $C^{op}$ satisfy AB3-AB5? ("nontrivial" means that there are nonzero objects in $C$)

Comment: No, see page 129 of Grothendieck's Tohoku paper.

Comment: If $C, C^{op}$ are both AB5 and they have a generator, then they are both locally finitely presentable. Categories such that $C,C^{op}$ are both locally presentable tend to be very trivial.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Not trivial in the sense of the question. If a category and its opposite are both locally presentable, it is a complete lattice.

Comment: Well, yeah, I shouldhave phrased the answer more on the lines of "although not the zero category, an AB5 and AB5* category tend to be quite trivial".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.

This is mentioned (with a hint for a proof) on page 129 of A. Grothendieck, *Sur quelques points d'algèbre homologique,* Tohoku Math. J. (2) 9, (1957), 119-221.

For a complete proof (albeit in somewhat different terminology) see Proposition III.1.10 in B. Mitchell, *Theory of categories,* Academic Press (1965).